# How to open an app through the terminal without rendering that terminal window useless for other commands?

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal, gtk, ubuntu-gnome

I am trying to use the terminal to open the file explorer nautilus. When I type the command `nautilus` into the terminal, I see the following output

```
(nautilus:5814): Gtk-WARNING **: 07:26:19.884: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2281:23: Expected a valid selector

(nautilus:5814): Gtk-WARNING **: 07:26:19.895: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:11535:3: '/*' in comment block

(nautilus:5814): Gtk-WARNING **: 07:26:19.895: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:11641:2: '/*' in comment block
Nautilus-Share-Message: 07:26:20.229: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
```

I can't run any other commands on that terminal window until I close the nautilus window. Its the same case with other apps run from the terminal like Firefox or Spotify. Is there any way to start an app and then still be able to use the same terminal window for other commands?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `&` after your command, e.g. start it like `appname &`.